# plantuml の ditaa モードの日本語対応はありませんか？

Tags: plantuml

ditaa そのものには 日本語対応する方法があります。
- 日本語化ditaaの利用 http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tamura70/20100317/org
- ditaa を日本語対応にする Awk スクリプト http://www.johf.com/log/20130113a.html

plantuml で 日本語を含む ditaa 記法の図を変換できるようにした版は どこかにあるでしょうか？